# Are complex subvarieties cycles in the sense of singular homology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given a $p$-codimensional complex subvariety $Z\subset M$ of a non singular complex projective variety $M$ of dimension $n$ we can define an element
$$\int_\hat{Z}i^*\in H^{2n-2p}_{dR}(M)^*:\omega\mapsto \int_\hat{Z}i^*\omega$$
where $\hat Z$ is desingularisation of $Z$. Since a smooth complex projective variety is a compex Kahler manifold we have
$$H^{2n-2p}_{dR}(M)^*\cong H^{2p}_{dR}(M)\cong H^{2p}_{sign}(M;\mathbb{C})\cong H_{2n-2p}(M;\mathbb{C})$$
And so we have a map from complex subvarieties of $M$ (i.e. from algebraic cycles) to singular homology.

Now my question is, what is the relation between the cycle class in homology we obtain in this way, and the subvariety $Z$?

In particular, are complex subvarieties cycles, i.e. images of continuous functions of a standard $p$-simplex? If (some) of them are, is the cycle class of $Z$ then the same as the cycle class under the above map?

---

Note I'm not asking whether every homology class is representable by a subvariety/submanifold, I know this is not true.

Comment: Cycles are not maps from simplices, they are *sums* of these with zero boundary. You can triangulate complex varieties (though this is hardly a trivial theorem). When you do, add up all the simplices, oriented the same way as the complex variety. This is the desired cycle.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks, that makes sense. Then an algebraic cycle is just a cycle obtained in this way; by triangulating a subvariety?